# ess-sup property

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measured space, and let $f \in L^p(\mu)$. I would like to show that
$$
|f| \leq \text{ess-sup}(|f|) \text{ a.e. on } X,
$$
where
$$
\text{ess-sup}(|f|) := \inf \{ \sup_{X \backslash N} |f| : N \in \mathcal{A}, \mu(N) = 0\}.
$$
I'm pretty sure it must be easy to show, but unfortunately I do not know how to handle this. I thought I could try to write the set of $x \in X$ not satisfying the property as a denumerable union of sets that are readily seen to have measure 0, but I did not succeed. Any hint on how to proceed from the above definition would be very appreciated.

Comment: Consider the sets $E(c) = \{ x : \lvert f(x)\rvert > c\}$. Note that $c_1 < c_2 \Rightarrow E(c_2) \subset E(c_1)$. Try to see that $\mu(E(c)) = 0 \iff c \geqslant \operatorname{ess-sup} (\lvert f\rvert)$.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Let $E := \{ x \in X : x > \text{ess-sup}(|f|) \}$. Let's say I proved the equivalence. Then, taking $c_n := \text{ess-sup}(|f|) + \frac{1}{n}$, we see that $E(c_n) \uparrow E$ and so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E(c_n)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0 = \mu(E)$, which was to be proved. Now, as for the equivalence, $\mu(E(c)) =0 \Rightarrow c \geq \sup_{X \backslash E(c)} |f| \geq \text{ess-sup}(|f|)$. But, I have difficulty in showing the converse. I wanted to proceed by contradiction and show that if $\mu(E(c)) \neq 0$, then $E(c)\backslash N \neq \emptyset$. Is that ok ?

Comment: In fact for the converse, I would prove the contrapositive. Suppose $\mu(E(c)) \neq 0$. Then, for every $N \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$, we would have that $E(c) \neq N$, because their measures aren't equal, and we would have $E(c) \not\subset N$ because of monotonicity. Hence we would have $E(c) \backslash N \neq \emptyset$ and therefore there would exist an $x \in (X \backslash N) \cap E(c)$. In turn this would imply that $\sup_{X\backslash N} |f| > c$ and since this would be true for every $N$, the $\text{ess-sup}(|f|)$ would have to be strictly greater than $c$. Is that ok ?

Comment: The $\sup\limits_{X\setminus N} \lvert f\rvert > c$ for all null sets $N$ would only allow you to deduce $\operatorname{ess-sup}(\lvert f\rvert) \geqslant c$ directly. For the strict inequality, you need a countable-union-of-null-sets-is-null-set argument, then it's okay. What I had in mind was that for $c > \operatorname{ess-sup}$, we find a null set $N$ such that $\sup\limits_{X\setminus N} \lvert f\rvert < c$. But then $E(c) \subset N$, hence $\mu(E(c)) = 0$. Use the countable union argument for the case $c=\operatorname{ess-sup}(\lvert f\rvert)$.

Comment: Alright ! Thank you for taking the time to answer back ! It's very kind of you and very appreciated.